# Connect 2 server sockets in JAVA

Tags: java, server, client, raw-sockets

I need to write a Java code that allows Client1Socket to connect to Server1Socket, Server1Socket to connect to Server2Socket and Server2Socket to connect to Client2Socket. Can anybody give me a simple example so I can apply in to my code? Thank you very much!

Comment: A `ServerSocket` can't connect to anything, let alone another `ServerSocket`. Rethink your requirement. As stated, it is absurd.

Comment: This is my assignment in uni and it requires me to do that :( unfortunately, the lecturer just explained about basic concepts of writing client/server sockets in programming and I have to research more

Comment: So is there any way to send data from one server to another one?

Comment: Thank you very much! The code is running well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server A will have to open a Socket to connect to server B, and it will have to copy data between that socket and the socket it accepted from client A.

Client B will have to connect to server B, not the other way around.

Server B will have to copy data between the socket it accepts from server A and the socket it accepts from client B.